# Is it possible to control the camera focus on WP7 Mango?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I'm creating an app where I make use of WP7 Mango's camera APIs. 
In the app I need to take pictures at different focal points, is there any possibility that I can set camera focus points programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need that method

```
PhotoCamera.FocusAtPoint(double x, double y);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera.focusatpoint(v=VS.92).aspx